# Как оптимизировать очередь laravel, в которой используются Guzzle Http запросы?

Tags: php, laravel, http, очередь, guzzle

Задача состоит в том, чтобы реализовать ревалидацию (ререндер) страниц на сайте, который управляется через Laravel. То есть, при каждом изменении собирается очередь из запросов к фронту, для каждой затронутой страницы. Проблема в том, что все эти HTTP запросы ждут ответа и тем самым очень сильно грузят сервер.

Можно ли как-то их отправить асинхронно?
Был ли у кого-то опыт работы с HTTP запросами в очередях, и как это можно оптимизировать?

Comment: У вас страницы статики рендерятся что ли? Если я правильно понял, можно попробовать убирать неактуальные задачи из очереди при добавлении новой

Comment: Да, страницы статики. Все задачи в очереди нужные.

Comment: Ну вот есть две задачи на обновление страницы home, допустим. Разве последняя прилетевшая не является самой актуальной (содержит самые актуальные данные), чтобы можно было из очереди выкинуть предыдущую задачу на рендер этой страницы?

Comment: звучит, как какой-то костыль.

Comment: Двух задач одинаковых не может быть. Они Все на разные страницы всегда. Суть в том, что много страниц и curl сильно нагружает сервер.